# Google Drive duplicated a file tens of thousands of times and now stuck syncing

Tags: google-drive, google-apps-sync

my google drive app starting bogging down and my files weren't syncing from the desktop app to the online google drive. Now my app is stuck syncing 17,000 files (that I didn't create or duplicate). Help.

Comment: Windows applications are off-topic here but on-topic on [su]. Is there a reason you don't log out of your desktop app, and clean up the files online and locally?